# How to handle ANR issue when application is idle

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog, blackberry-android

My BB10 ported android Application ,if kept idle for 15 mins,I am getting this ANR issue,How to handle this scenario.

I am not able to reproduce in my device,But I am getting this issue in client device.I am not able to reproduce this issue.

Comment: try to get some `logcat`, or use some library to get the crash report, like Flurry, or ask the client to click on the report button of ANR dialog, ans see it in the app store.

Comment: Does your do anything during this time? And is it in the foreground or did the customer send it to the active frames?